# How to convert this vscode-languageserver-node-lsp-sample to use on atom and vim?

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

from this link [https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide](https://stackoverflow.com) i understood that we can use lsp on multiple IDE`s but I dont know once developed how to deploy it to other IDE? I can package it to vsix to work on vscode but how on atom and vim?

Help needed in converting this lsp sample (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-sample) so to use on atom and vim with minimal changes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Atom but if you're eager to use Vim or Neovim (nvim), you'll find a wealth of packages available that offer Language Server Protocol (LSP) support for virtually every popular programming language and tool.

For a seamless Neovim experience, consider using a pre-configured setup like NVChad (https://nvchad.com/). NVChad not only comes preloaded with the essentials but also boasts remarkable speed, extensive configurability, and rock-solid reliability. It's ready to enhance your coding journey out of the box.

Comment: Hi sir, but i want this lsp-sample that i provided to be used on other IDE's whats the process? As per my knowledge lsp should work on other IDE's thats why we use this protocol. correct me if i am wrong and help me with this process. Thnaks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/integrate-language-server-with-vs-code-extension-ffe8f33a79cf